# список из CardView + databinding

Tags: java, android, cardview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужно в Main список из CardView(Изображение и текст, перекидывающее на другие экраны),как правильно реализовать через dataBinding и какой layout использовать лучше? Как в Main лучше обработать переход на другой активити?

Comment: приложите ваш код, дополните вопрос, вопрос должен вмещать в себя только один вопрос а не несколько, конкретизируйте пожалуйста

Comment: еще не написал, препод только визуально показал